# How to freeze a column in interactive grid in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a interactive grid with many columns. I want a certain column to be always placed at first position in the row.

```
**Has Role**   Name   User_ID  Address   Phone number
```

Basically I want to freeze the column 'Role' so that user can not change its position in runtime. He can change the positions of others columns like Name, USER_ID, Address, Phone number.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Hi.. does somebody has any idea..how we can do this..?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - New answer. I edited the previous answer, because it would be too long to fit in a comment.

I suppose you could freeze that column and disable the freeze/unfreeze option in the header with the following. Keep in mind, this disables the freeze options on the **whole** interactive grid. Add it to the **Execute when Page Loads** section.

```
$("#ig_id").on("gridactivatecolumnheader", function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ig_id").find("[data-option='freeze']").remove();
    },
               1);
}
            );
```

To do it on a single column, go to it on its column on the **advanced** section, and add the following in the **JavaScript Initialization Code**. You'll basically deactivate the header actions menu form appearing, thus not allowing people to change it's freezing options. Not sure though if the order can be changed. I haven't tested that. I'll give it a try here as well.

```
function(config) {
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
        noHeaderActivate: true
    };  
    return config;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am sorry I didn't made my requirement quite clear. Actually, currently I can already change the order of the columns from the website. And I want this functionality to be always available for all the columns except "Has Role". i.e I do not want the users to change the position of "Has Role" but he should be allowed to very well change the positions of other columns..Do you have any idea if and how that can be done ?

Comment: I changed the answer. I did also test the second option, even having the column frozen, you can still change it through the actions menu. You might need a different solution then. If your requirement states that the use can change the column order, I don't know how to do it.

On my application I just set the order to be what we developers chose to be (with tips from users) and disable the editing options for the report. Options such as hide might cause some damage in the hands of unexperienced users, so we rather not have it available, for instance.

Comment: Just something interesting to note, the first solution that I shared was working back on the 5.1.4, now that I'm using the 18.2 version, it's not working as intended anymore. The second solution still works, however, it disables the header, so the user can't use its options. They should be able to still use the action button, if you have it available.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this link will help? I think its a linked question though not the answer required here. I had to look up how to freeze the first column on an IG so that the user could scroll through the other columns without losing sight of the first.

[Apex freeze frames on interactive grids](http://oracle-apex-book.blogspot.com/2017/06/interactive-grid-features-in-oracle.html)

The user can manually freeze frames himself on any column in the latest versions of Apex.

Regards